# "and" statement in list comprehension python

Tags: python, arrays, list-comprehension

I have an array that needs certain elements removed. I am trying to have list comprehension do this for me, but it is not working.

It is a two dimensional array.  For each row in the array if the first item, a str, meets two qualifications I would like it to be removed.  However, when I use an "and" statement it only looks at the first statement.  Why is this and how do you correct it?

```
act_array = [row for row in act_array if row[0][-4:] != '0660' and row[0][0] != '4' ]
```

So I this example I want to copy all items that do not start with a 4 and whose last 4 chars do not equal 0660

Thanks

Comment: What makes you think "it only looks at the first statement"?  Can you provide example data showing the problem?

Answer (score 5):

> ... if the first item, a str, meets two qualifications I would like it to be removed...

So, you want all of the rows which end with `0660`, and all of the rows that start with `4`, but none of the rows that have both.

You have a logic bug, your condition

```
if row[0][-4:] != '0660' and row[0][0] != '4' ]
#              ^         ^^^           ^
```

is logically equivalent, by deMorgan's law, to :

```
if not (row[0][-4:] == '0660' or row[0][0] == '4') ]
#  ^^^              ^^        ^^           ^^
```

(note, the negation is distributed and the `and`'s and `or`'s are swapped.  That means you filter the elements which satisfy either condition.  Fix it with one of:

```
if row[0][-4:] != '0660' or row[0][0] != '4' ]
#              ^         ^^           ^
```

or

```
if not (row[0][-4:] == '0660' and row[0][0] == '4') ]
#  ^^^              ^^        ^^^           ^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work as expected:

```
In [6]: act_array=[['4X0660'], ['4X1111'], ['1X0660'], ['1X1111']]
In [7]: [row for row in act_array if row[0][-4:] != '0660' and row[0][0] != '4' ]
Out[7]: [['1X1111']]
```